# Page divided to 50% left div and 50% right div , need to change order of appearance of left and right children on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container with 2 divs, left and right , each div takes 50% of the screen size.
On mobile, I show left and right as 100% width and flex column but I need to change to order of appearance
of items from each div, for example
on desktop
left shows 1,2,3
right shows 4,5,6
on mobile I want to show
1,2,4
3,5,6

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use order property and display:flex to accomplish this. Check the below code snippet in full screen and you can see it in action. Hope this helps.

```css
.parent{
  display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child{
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .child{
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
  }
  .order-1{
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;
    -ms-flex-order:1;
    order:1;
  }
  .order-2{
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:3;
    -ms-flex-order:2;
    order:2;
  }
  .order-3{
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:4;
    -ms-flex-order:3;
    order:3;
  }
  .order-4{
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:5;
    -ms-flex-order:4;
    order:4;
  }
  .order-5{
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:6;
    -ms-flex-order:5;
    order:5;
  }
  .order-6{
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:7;
    -ms-flex-order:6;
    order:6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child order-1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="child order-2">
  2
  </div>
  <div class="child order-4">
  3
  </div>
  <div class="child order-3">
  4
  </div>
  <div class="child order-5">
  5
  </div>
  <div class="child order-6">
  6
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem also required me to use masonry layout since each block has it's own size and the combo of your answer and this https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/WNNwmp
solved my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the `container` to `display:flex` and use `order` property on child components like in this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_order). Combine this with `@media` rules to use it only on mobile version of your page.

```css
#main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  display: flex;
}

#main div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

/* Safari 6.1+ */
div#myRedDIV   {-webkit-order: 2;}
div#myBlueDIV  {-webkit-order: 4;}
div#myGreenDIV {-webkit-order: 3;}
div#myPinkDIV  {-webkit-order: 1;}

/* Standard syntax */
div#myRedDIV   {order: 1;}
div#myBlueDIV  {order: 2;}
div#myGreenDIV {order: 3;}
div#myPinkDIV  {order: 4;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;" id="myRedDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;" id="myBlueDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;" id="myGreenDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;" id="myPinkDIV"></div>
</div>
```